# Request had invalid authentication credentials. on the compute engine vm

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a default n1 instance on the GCloud with preinstalled java and latest google sdk. When I run code locally within appengine:devserver which connects to the real pubsub subscription, it works correct. If I do the same on the Instance I get an authentication error:

```
[INFO] SEVERE: 401 OK
[INFO] {
[INFO]   "code" : 401,
[INFO]   "errors" : [ {
[INFO]     "domain" : "global",
[INFO]     "message" : "Request had invalid authentication credentials.",
[INFO]     "reason" : "unauthorized"
[INFO]   } ],
[INFO]   "message" : "Request had invalid authentication credentials.",
[INFO]   "status" : "UNAUTHENTICATED"
[INFO] }
```

All permissions are full or read/write/enabled for this instance. I absolutely have no idea why error happens?

I did `gcloud init` with the same credentials locally and on the instance.

upd: I also tested pulling: `gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull mysubscription-tag` - ok

Answer (score 2):

Simply had to run `gcloud beta auth application-default login`.
But I spent a half of a day until found it [there](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication).
I thought it should be enough to `gcloud init`. As alternative you can use google authentication via Google OAuth2 but that is hard way.